# Getting location from client

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I'm loading a Google Map, map loads fine, and everything but doesn't zoom into location and for some reason my autocomplete stopped working.

I've converted the activity to a fragment for memory purpose anyone have any ideas as to why it won't zoom in? This is my code in map fragment:

```
async void AutoCompleteOption_Click(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //to soft keyboard hide
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)Activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            inputManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(txtSearch.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.NotAlways);
            map.Clear();

            if (txtSearch.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                var builtString = new StringBuilder();
                builtString.Append(strGeoCodingUrl);
                builtString.Append("?address=").Append(txtSearch.Text);
                string stringResult = await fnDownloadString(builtString.ToString());

                if (stringResult == "Exception")
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Unable to connect to server!!!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }

                objGeoCodeJSONClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoCodeJSONClass>(stringResult);
                LatLng Position = new LatLng(objGeoCodeJSONClass.results[0].geometry.location.lat, objGeoCodeJSONClass.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
                updateCameraPosition(Position);
                MarkOnMap("MyLocation", Position);
            }

        }

public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            map = googleMap;
            var locationManager = Activity.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
            if (locationManager.AllProviders.Contains(LocationManager.NetworkProvider)
                && locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider))
            {
                locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 2000, 1, this);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "The Network Provider does not exist or is not enabled!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
            map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: use function called gmap.moveCamera();

Answer (score 0):

// Zoom in, animating the camera.

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
```

Comment: i think theres a problem with this line:  locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 2000, 1, this);  from my knowledge this shouldnt work in a fragment but its not underlined